# Watson Chat Bot see logs of conversations

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have a question regarding the IBM Watson chat bot. All my intents and entities are ready and in some of my nodes I used "literal" function to store the input of the user. Now I **want to document** the chat somehow and I want to be able to see especially those stored values within the documentation. Is documenting the chat possible (e.g as a notepad file, etc.) ? Thank you for your support in advance. Ciao!

Answer (score 1):

I dont have any code to actually help you, but you can get the logs via the /logs api here:
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/curl.html?curl
which would contain all the info you're looking for, then you could write it to a file or database or whatever you want.